# The use of :alert (or :notice) with the render method, from the Ruby On Rails guide called 'Layouts and Rendering in Rails', does not work for me:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The use of :alert (or :notice) with the render method, from the Ruby On Rails guide called 'Layouts and Rendering in Rails' at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html, does not work for me

That's the sample code provided in the guide:

```
    def index
      @books = Book.all
    end

    def show
      @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
      if @book.nil?
        @books = Book.all
        render "index", :alert => 'Your book was not found!'
      end
    end
```

I have a hello controller that looks like this:

```
    class HelloController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @counter = 5
      end
      def bye
        @counter = 4
        render "index", :alert => 'Alert message!'
      end
    end
```

My index.html.erb view looks like that:

```
    <ul>
    <% @counter.times do |i| %>
      <li><%= i %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

When accessing `http://localhost:3000/hello/bye`, I see the index view, i.e. a list of numbers from 1 to 4 as expected, but there's no 'Alert message!' alert showing.

My layout uses this to show alert messages:

```
    <% flash.each do |k, v| %>
      <div id="<%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 32):

I'm confused as to why that Rails Guide mentions using flash values in `render`, since they only appear to work in `redirect_to` at the moment. I think you'll find your approach works if you put a `flash.now[:alert] = 'Alert message!'` before your render method call.

Edit: this is a [flaw in the guides that will be fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f9f6fc7a91fecc7a52c812d2900b9ae5d4636743), you should use the separate method call to set the flash prior to calling render.

Comment: Appears to be a bug that was fixed in the latest unreleased version of the guide: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks Ari, found the change for that just now.

Answer (score 29):

Try

```
  def bye
    @counter  = 4
    flash.now[:error] = "Your book was not found"
    render :index
  end
```

Answer (score 12):

Normally you would do something like:

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User saved"
else
  flash[:alert] = "You haz errors!"
  render :action => :new
end
```

What you want to do is (and I like this syntax much better):

```
if @user.save
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User saved"
else
  render :action => :new, :alert => "You haz errors!"
end
```

...however, that isn't valid for `ActionController::Flash#render`.

**But**, you can extend `ActionController::Flash#render` to do **exactly** what you want:

Create `config/initializers/flash_renderer.rb` with the following content:

```
module ActionController
  module Flash

    def render(*args)
      options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.last : {}

      if alert = options.delete(:alert)
        flash[:alert] = alert
      end

      if notice = options.delete(:notice)
        flash[:notice] = notice
      end

      if other = options.delete(:flash)
        flash.update(other)
      end

      super(*args)
    end

  end
end
```

Ref: http://www.perfectline.co/blog/2011/11/adding-flash-message-capability-to-your-render-calls-in-rails-3/